# Error trying to " import epipy " or " from epipy import * " in python (using pycharm IDE)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, interpreter

Python throwing an error when I try to import epipy even though I installed the package to the project interpreter (python file's interpreter is also set to same environment)

- Tried using an absolute import; from epipy import *
- Tried importing a specific function e.g. from epipy import case_tree
- Tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package

My code:

import pandas as pd

import epipy

I expect to import installed packages with no errors, received error below:

```
/Users/Noelle/Python/stats/bin/python /Users/Noelle/Python/stats/basic_analytics.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Noelle/Python/stats/basic_analytics.py", line 2, in <module>
    import epipy
  File "/Users/Noelle/Python/stats/lib/python3.6/site-packages/epipy/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .analyses import generation_analysis, reproduction_number, create_2x2
  File "/Users/Noelle/Python/stats/lib/python3.6/site-packages/epipy/analyses.py", line 88
    print 'Summary of reproduction numbers'
                                          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('Summary of reproduction numbers')?
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: "`SyntaxError`" That is a *very* good hint that the installed package is not made for your version. `print` in Python2 is a statement, but in Python3 it is a function that needs parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install from pip or directly from github? According to [this post](https://github.com/cmrivers/epipy/issues/15), the pip version is only compatible with python 2, for py3.x you have to download the github version directly

Answer (score 0):

That error is because print is being called:

```
print'Summary of reproduction numbers'
```

Instead of:

```
print('Summary of reproduction numbers')
```

Python 3 print syntax is different from python 2

EDIT:
Seems this is because the epipy package you installed is for python 2 and not python 3

Comment: The OP doesn't have any print statements, and the traceback indicates the error occurs in `site-packages/epipy/init.py`. This looks like compatibility, as your edit suggests